# setTimeout doesn't let me append to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I suspect that the `setTimeout` part of my code is to blame, however I can append to the `document.body` part of the DOM without an issue. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let adblock = document.getElementById(`adblock`);
    
    let fake_ad = document.createElement("div");
    fake_ad.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    // Hide it from viewport
    fake_ad.setAttribute("style", "top: -999px; position: fixed;");
    // Add some Adblock bait classes
    fake_ad.className = "adsbox ad-300x250 banner-ad";
    // Append the ad to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(fake_ad);
    // Wait 500ms for the adblocker to do its job
    window.setTimeout(function() {
     if (fake_ad.offsetHeight === 0) {
      // Add class .ab to body
      document.body.classList.add("ab");
      // For testing
      console.log("Adblock is enabled!");
      adblock.innerHTML = "present!";
      document.body.innerHTML += "Adblock is enabled!";
     } else {
      // For testing
      console.log("Adblock is disabled!");
      document.body.innerHTML += "Adblock is disabled!";
     }
     // Remove the fake ad from DOM
     document.body.removeChild(fake_ad);
    }, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Adblocking is <strong id="adblock"></strong></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where does your JavaScript appear in the HTML?  If it's *before* the body, then the "adblock" element will not be in the DOM when it runs.

Comment: It's included as an async script in the head: `<script src="test.js" async></script>`

Comment: That could be a problem. All DOM operations should be executed after `document`'s `onLoad` event is triggered.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/yLt6319m/1/ I suspect it's what Pointy has suggested. Try adding it as a script tag after body.

Comment: Well it'd be good practice to test whether the `getElementById()` call for "adblock" returns a non-null result. You could put the code in a "load" handler or move the `<script>` to the end of the body.

Comment: @Pointy, I've moved `<script>` to the end of the body. Same result. Furthermore, I've tested if `adblock` is null. It is not.

Comment: @wombat are you getting a warning in console such as "unable to modify dom from async script while document is open"?

Comment: Well your snippet works fine here in Stackoverflow.  What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: @SalmanA I am not getting any errors. I am just not getting the desired results. @Pointy, the snippet doesn't work fine. The first line should be `Adblocking is present!` or `Adblocking is `  if it is disabled, at the moment, because the `else` statement doesn't have a `adblocker.innerHTML` declaration.

Comment: The variable `fake_ad` does not points to the DOM element added to body (it has not `parentNode`). When appending it, try getting the return value: `fake_ad = document.body.appendChild(fake_ad);`

Comment: Oh. My mistake. The code works fine, I was just confused that in the snippet it says that the adblocker is disabled while my browser has one (I don't know where the snipper is executed), and in my test environment the browser has no adblock, creating some confusion. Furthermore, the lack of a `adblock.innerHTML = "disabled!";` in the `else` statement added to the fiasco. Sorry, guys, for wasting your time.

Comment: I just discovered the same thing as you. Adblocker in Chrome injects a stylesheet that gives `adblock` a `display: none` by default which confused me as well. Here's a fiddle that renames `id="adblock"` and different results show: https://jsfiddle.net/yLt6319m/3/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your javascript so that it runs after the window has loaded. If you try manipulating the DOM beforehand the objects won't exist.

Something like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  code block here...
}
```

Alternatively you can remove `async` from your script tag and append it after the closing `<body>` tag and before the closing `<html>` tag.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yLt6319m/2/

Comment: Your example isn't working. It has the same results as mine.

Comment: Do you want it to say `Adblock is enabled!` or `Adblock is disabled!`?

Comment: Per comments we want it to say `Adblock is present!` on the first line. Here's an updated fiddle that renames `id="adblock"` to `id="block_me"`. https://jsfiddle.net/yLt6319m/3/

Comment: Tested in `codepen.io` as well, same result. Thank you, that is a nice discovery! :) How did you find it?

Comment: I ran into the same problem you did. I have adblocker running in chrome and didn't realize they were also blocking for `id="adblock`. It was very confusing until I inspected it and realized what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the code executed inside the `setTimeout` is executed after a garbage collection cycle deletes `fake_ad`, as it is not beeing referenced by any active function. You can try passing the `fake_ad` variable to the `setTimeout` call, so it has a reference that prevents beeing garbage collected:

```
window.setTimeout(function(fake_ad) {
...
}, 500, fake_ad);
```

Comment: No, the garbage collector will not delete the value of `fake_ad` because it refers to an element that's been added to the DOM.